# Python: Parse elapsed time (minutes : seconds) to seconds

Tags: python, parsing, datetime, time

Let's say I have a string like `'2:19.83 blah blah...blah blah'` where the format is `minutes:seconds.centiseconds blah...` and `blah` can represent any sequence of characters other than a newline.

I want to parse and get the number of seconds rounded down.  So in the above example, the result would be `139`.

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would first get the time portion from the string

```
>>> newstring=s.split('.',1)[0]
```

Then I would read it using strptime...

```
>>> tt=time.strptime(newstring,"%M:%S")
```

and then finally, get the time in seconds.

```
>>> tt.tm_min * 60 + tt.tm_sec
```

Not a 1-liner, but pretty simple...

Comment: it should be: `tt = time.strptime(s, '%M:%S')`, %m is months, %s is invalid

Comment: @Boud -- Thanks.  That's what I get for not looking at the format codes carefully.

Answer (score 3):

How about this one? Not particularly pretty perhaps I admit, but functional and easy to comprehend I think.

Given

```
s = '2:19.83'
```

and

```
tmp = s.split(':')
min = int(tmp[0])
sec = int(tmp[1].split('.')[0])

total_secs = min * 60 + sec   
print total_secs
```

yields

```
139
```

Comment: I think this is prettier than a regex ... regex is great, but it is overkill in a situation like this (and hard to read).

Comment: Sorry for the Me-Too comment, but since I proposed the regex solution, I have the right to say 'You're right!' I like this better too. +1

Comment: Thanks .. my limited knowledge often leads me to "Simple is better than complex." solutions :)

Comment: `min` is a builtin function and should in general be avoided as a variable name

Answer (score 2):

```
sum(x*y for x,y in zip(map(int, re.findall(r'^(\d+):(\d+)', string)[0]), [60,1]))
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems to do what you need:

```
>>> s = '2:19.83 blah blah...blah blah'
>>> import re
>>> m = re.match(r'(?P<min>\d):(?P<sec>\d{2})\.\d+', s)
>>> if m:
...     seconds = (int(m.group('min')) * 60) + int(m.group('sec'))
...     print seconds
139
```

Comment: This gives me a pickling error using the python shell at http://shell.appspot.com/

Comment: Well, as you can see, it works in my Python 2.7 shell. That's a copy/paste. I cannot explain your pickling error.

Comment: Might be an issue with python 2.5... I'll look at it in my shell on my home computer when I get the chance.

Comment: Seems to be a bug in shell.appspot.com. I also have 2.5 installed locally and tried it here. No problem. Also confirmed the pickling error on shell.appspot. Weird.